# Finding next relevant row based on 2 (or more column values)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    TS                      TAGNAME VALUE
1   2019-11-25 09:00:00.000 TAG1    TRUE
2   2019-11-25 09:01:00.000 TAG2    TRUE
3   2019-11-25 09:02:00.000 TAG1    FALSE
4   2019-11-25 09:03:00.000 TAG2    FALSE
5   2019-11-25 09:04:00.000 TAG1    TRUE
6   2019-11-25 09:05:00.000 TAG1    FALSE
7   2019-11-25 09:06:00.000 TAG1    TRUE
8   2019-11-25 09:07:00.000 TAG2    TRUE
9   2019-11-25 09:08:00.000 TAG3    TRUE
10  2019-11-25 09:09:00.000 TAG1    FALSE
11  2019-11-25 09:10:00.000 TAG2    FALSE
12  2019-11-25 09:11:00.000 TAG3    FALSE
13  2019-11-25 09:12:00.000 TAG1    TRUE
14  2019-11-25 09:13:00.000 TAG1    TRUE
15  2019-11-25 09:14:00.000 TAG1    FALSE
```

I want to add a column to this dataframe that should contain the timestamp of the "next opposite" value of the same TAGNAME.
So in this example I want this:

```
    TS                      TAGNAME VALUE
1   2019-11-25 09:00:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:02:00.000 (from index 3)
2   2019-11-25 09:01:00.000 TAG2    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:03:00.000 (from index 4)
3   2019-11-25 09:02:00.000 TAG1    FALSE   2019-11-25 09:04:00.000 (from index 5)
4   2019-11-25 09:03:00.000 TAG2    FALSE   2019-11-25 09:07:00.000 (from index 8)
5   2019-11-25 09:04:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:05:00.000 (from index 6)
6   2019-11-25 09:05:00.000 TAG1    FALSE   2019-11-25 09:06:00.000 (from index 7)
7   2019-11-25 09:06:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:09:00.000 (from index 10)
8   2019-11-25 09:07:00.000 TAG2    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:10:00.000 (from index 11)
9   2019-11-25 09:08:00.000 TAG3    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:11:00.000 (from index 12)
10  2019-11-25 09:09:00.000 TAG1    FALSE   2019-11-25 09:12:00.000 (from index 13)
11  2019-11-25 09:10:00.000 TAG2    FALSE   (EMPTY, no "next" found)
12  2019-11-25 09:11:00.000 TAG3    FALSE   (EMPTY, no "next" found)
13  2019-11-25 09:12:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:14:00.000 (from index 15)
14  2019-11-25 09:13:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:14:00.000 (from index 15)
15  2019-11-25 09:14:00.000 TAG1    FALSE   (EMPTY, no "next" found)
```

Note that some rows might not even have a "partner" and sometimes I migh have two or more "TRUE" or "FALSE" for one opposite value.

The ultimate goal is to calculate the time interval between each value change of the same TAGNAME.

```
    TS                      TAGNAME VALUE   PARTNER TS                                  INTERVAL
1   2019-1-25 09:00:00.000  TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:02:00.000 (from index 3)      00:02:00
2   2019-11-25 09:01:00.000 TAG2    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:03:00.000 (from index 4)      00:02:00
3   2019-11-25 09:02:00.000 TAG1    FALSE   2019-11-25 09:04:00.000 (from index 5)      00:02:00
4   2019-11-25 09:03:00.000 TAG2    FALSE   2019-11-25 09:07:00.000 (from index 8)      00:04:00
5   2019-11-25 09:04:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:05:00.000 (from index 6)      00:01:00
6   2019-11-25 09:05:00.000 TAG1    FALSE   2019-11-25 09:06:00.000 (from index 7)      00:01:00
7   2019-11-25 09:06:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:09:00.000 (from index 10)     00:03:00
8   2019-11-25 09:07:00.000 TAG2    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:10:00.000 (from index 11)     00:03:00
9   2019-11-25 09:08:00.000 TAG3    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:11:00.000 (from index 12)     00:03:00
10  2019-11-25 09:09:00.000 TAG1    FALSE   2019-11-25 09:12:00.000 (from index 13)     00:04:00
11  2019-11-25 09:10:00.000 TAG2    FALSE   (EMPTY, no "next" found)                    NaN
12  2019-11-25 09:11:00.000 TAG3    FALSE   (EMPTY, no "next" found)                    NaN
13  2019-11-25 09:12:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:14:00.000 (from index 15)     00:02:00
14  2019-11-25 09:13:00.000 TAG1    TRUE    2019-11-25 09:14:00.000 (from index 15)     00:01:00
15  2019-11-25 09:14:00.000 TAG1    FALSE   (EMPTY, no "next" found)                    NaN
```

I guess I can achieve this by doing a good old "for-loop" but it seems very suboptimal and probably will be very slow.
Is there some way to do it in a smart way in pandas?

Comment: can you give a sample of the `ultimate goal`, it might be easier to obtain than to get that intermediate column

Comment: Yes, sorry if I was coming from too far away. I edited the question above

Comment: I thought the ultimate goal would be the difference in time, `['PARTNER TS'] = row 1: 2 minutes, row 2: 2 minutes row 4: 4 minutes` and so on

Comment: Yes, exactly right. That is what I have in the INTERVAL column in my example (different format)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
df['diff'] = (df.assign(c=df.groupby(['TAGNAME','VALUE']).cumcount())
                .sort_values(['c'])
                .groupby('TAGNAME').TS.shift(-1)
                .sub(df['TS'])
             )
```

Output:

```
                      TS TAGNAME  VALUE              diff                                                             
1.0  2019-11-25 09:00:00   TAG1    True          00:02:00
2.0  2019-11-25 09:01:00   TAG2    True          00:02:00
3.0  2019-11-25 09:02:00   TAG1   False          00:02:00
4.0  2019-11-25 09:03:00   TAG2   False          00:04:00
5.0  2019-11-25 09:04:00   TAG1    True          00:01:00
6.0  2019-11-25 09:05:00   TAG1   False          00:01:00
7.0  2019-11-25 09:06:00   TAG1    True          00:03:00
8.0  2019-11-25 09:07:00   TAG2    True          00:03:00
9.0  2019-11-25 09:08:00   TAG3    True          00:03:00
10.0 2019-11-25 09:09:00   TAG1   False          00:03:00
11.0 2019-11-25 09:10:00   TAG2   False               NaT
12.0 2019-11-25 09:11:00   TAG3   False               NaT
13.0 2019-11-25 09:12:00   TAG1    True          00:02:00
14.0 2019-11-25 09:13:00   TAG1    True               NaT
15.0 2019-11-25 09:14:00   TAG1   False -1 days +23:59:00
```

Explanation:

```
# this creates a new column with the order of occurrence for each VALUE within TAGNAME
df.assign(c=df.groupby(['TAGNAME','VALUE']).cumcount())

# sort the data by the that order of occurrence
sort_values(['TAGNAME','c'])

# groupby and shift to get the corresponding timestamp
groupby('TAGNAME').TS.shift(-1)

# subtract the original timestamp
sub(df['TS'])
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem can be optimally solved by pandas merges.

If df is your shown dataframe such that:

```
index = pd.date_range('25/11/2019 09:00:00.000', periods=15, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['TS'] = index
df['TAGNAME'] = ['TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG1', 'TAG1', 'TAG1', 'TAG2', 
                 'TAG3', 'TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG3', 'TAG1', 'TAG1', 'TAG1']
df['VALUE'] = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, 
False, True, True, False]
```

& to convert it to the final dataframe as shown by you need a couple of merges:

```
merged = df.merge(df, on = 'TAGNAME', how = 'outer')

# adding conditions
merged = merged[(merged['VALUE_x'] != merged['VALUE_y']) & (merged['TS_x'] < 
merged['TS_y'])]

# Taking a minimum next time that matches the TAGNAME
merged = merged.groupby('TS_x').min().reset_index()[['TS_x', 'TS_y']]

#renaming columns for merge in the next step and to align with final required df
merged.rename(columns = {'TS_x': 'TS', 'TS_y':'PARTNER TS'}, inplace = True)

# finally appending to the main dataframe
df = df.merge(merged, on = 'TS', how = 'left')

# calculating the interval
df['INTERVAL'] = df['PARTNER TS'] - df['TS']
```